# C++ file handling reading select data

Tags: c++, file-io

I have created a struct and outputted the data held into a basic textfile using the file stream. I now want to be able to get the user to enter a ID number and then the programme should get the data for that record from the text file instead of displaying everything contained within it.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Are your records fixed size or variable size?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some methods for fetching a data record from a file.

**Direct Access**
This involves seeking to a position in the file and reading the record.
The data must be fixed length.
The file position must be known (for example, fetching from a dictionary, associative array, etc.).

Example:

```
input_file.seekg(position, ios::beg);
input_file.read((signed char *)&my_record, sizeof(my_record));
```

**Reading file into memory, searching memory**
This technique is good when the records are of variable length or the position of the record is unknown.
Allocate a large memory area, often called a buffer, read into the buffer, then search the buffer.

Example:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(1024*1024);
input_file.read((signed char *) &buffer[0], 1024*1024);
```

**Memory mapped files**
Memory mapping files treats a file as memory.  The operating system handles the fetching of data from the file into memory.
This is operating system specific and you would have to look up the API.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
struct Record
{
    int id;
    string name;
    float amount;
};

int main()
{
    fstream f; f.open("data.txt", ios::in);

    int id; Record p[5];
    cout << "Enter ID num: ";
    cin >> id;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        f >> p[i].id;
        getline(f, p[i].name, '*');
        f >> p[i].amount;

        if(id == p[i].id)
            cout << p[i].name << " " << p[i].amount << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Data file:

```
15 chris* 50.5
30 tim* 65.2
50 george* 4.0
20 bob* 60.3
60 mary* 20.2
```

Comment: can you explain getline(f, p[i].name, '*'), I am not clear on the * is it a pointer.

Comment: It's a delimiter for getline. Basically, that's where getline stops inputting, so only the names are extracted and stored into `string name`.